# get current extension name in Controller

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

how can I get the current Extension or Plugin Name in a Controllers Actions? Also if the Action is within a Controller derived from AbstractPlugin?

```
$ext = get???
$plugin = get???
$this->uriBuilder->uriFor('ActionName', $params, 'Controller', $ext , $plugin);
```

regards
n00n

Answer (score 8):

The extension name is in every controller as global variable and can be accessed via `$this->extensionName`.

As there can be different plugins accessing the action in a controller, you can get the plugin name in the request via `$this->request->getPluginName()`.

Comment: The property extensionName of AbstractController has been removed in v10 #87627.
You can get the extension name with:
$this->request->getControllerExtensionName();
and the extension key with:
$this->request->getControllerExtensionKey();

Answer (score 0):

```
$extensionName = explode( '\\', $this::class )[1];

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
$extensionKey = GeneralUtility::camelCaseToLowerCaseUnderscored(explode('\\', $this::class )[1] );
```

request is protected.
using $obj::class works also outside the controller context.

example: in a called static method.